# Android emulator for samsung galaxy tab 2

Tags: android-emulator, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

I am using MonoDevelop to create an app and I was looking for an emulator for the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 tablet.  I found this link:

[Samsung Site](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator)

But I do not understand how to install it into the Mono Environment.  I copied the folder to the avd's folder on my mac, but it does not show up.  I think I am missing a .ini file but I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think that's an emulator for a Tab1 - not a Tab2.

For Tab2 emulation, I've generally just set up an ICS emulator with roughly appropriate settings - e.g. WXGA800, "Abstracted LCD density" 240.

---

Please be aware that there are some very significant differences between Tab1 and Tab2 - e.g. Tab1 falsely reports its screen density to the operating system - so UIs appear larger - see [Samsung Galaxy Tab 7inch - Layout Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563811/samsung-galaxy-tab-7inch-layout-issues)

---

Regardless, if you want to install the Tab1 emulator, then don't copy files around yourself - instead try following the instructions on that site - **except** that instead of using the SDK and AVD managers from within eclipse, then you can run them from within VS or MonoDevelop - or you can run them from within the Android SDK folder.

Comment: I was trying to use the SDK and AVD Managers from MonoDevelop but when i was going through the steps, I could not figure out step 1 which states: From the Android SDK and AVD Manager, select the following :
Available packages => Third Party Add-ons => Samsung Electronics add-ons => GALAXY Tab by Samsung Electronics., Android API 8, revision 1
 - I could not find Available Packages, Third Party Add Ons, of anything for Samsung.