# Text size with different resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, text, resolution

i am using a galaxy tab 1, 7inch hdpi and a galaxy tab plus, 7 inch hdpi but more resolution, and in my application, the text can be read fine in galaxy tab but in galaxy tab plus there are too much small. 
Im using sp in font size and layout-large. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: may be you can find answer from here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-devices

Answer (score 34):

This should be some help for you if you want to set size programmatically. Text will show in the same size on each device

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("text");
text.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

Comment: I tried this for `Canvas.setTextSize()`. It does help, though the text is not the same size on the 2 devices on which I tested.

Comment: Doesn't work if the screen size is big but the density is low.

Comment: but isn't the density in dp? it likes setting the text size in xml to 16dp which isn't right i think

Answer (score 19):

By hardware specifications Galaxy Tab 1 is MDPI device, but because it uses Android 2.x Samsung set it programmatically to use HDPI resources. So I can advice you to make following:

1. Create file `dimens.xml` in `values` directory.
2. Put there `<dimen name="font_size">30sp</dimen>`. This is default font size.
3. Create file `dimens.xml` in `values-large` directory.
4. Put there `<dimen name="font_size">20sp</dimen>`. This is font size for galaxy tab 1.
5. Create file `dimens.xml` in `values-sw600dp` directory.
6. Put there `<dimen name="font_size">30sp</dimen>`. This is font size for other tablets with Android 3.x and newer.
7. In layout specify `android:textSize="@dimens/font_size"`

Comment: why do you need to put the text dimension in different values folder??  Android treats the default values folder as one for the mdpi device and scale it based on current device configuration. If device is in large category then it will scale it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Because Galaxy Tab 1 is MDPI, but scales text to HDPI size

Comment: size and resolution are two different things. A small size device can lie in the hdpi category and a large device in the ldpi category. So how using values-large and values-small is going to be of any help here??

Comment: values-large will be used only by tablets with Android 2.x, which has this scaling problem, any other large screen device will use values-sw600dp

Comment: Yep, that means any large or xlarge screen devices with api level >= 11 will use `values-sw600dp` with default font size. Large screen devices with api < 11 will use smaller font size from `values-large`. Small or medium screen devices with any api level will use default font size from `values`. That's why we need these three folders.

Comment: this is the best way !

Answer (score 16):

you just need to create different folders related to density or screen size
like

**Option 1.**

```
values-large
values-small
values-normal
```

For more explanation check this link...

[Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

**Option 2.**

```
mTextView.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

this will give **TextSize** depending on density..

Comment: Yes but the 2 tablets use large layouts but with diferent resolution, then i will have same problem.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

like this

```
android:textSize= "10sp"
```

**sp**

> Scale-independent Pixels - This is like the dp unit, but it is also
>   scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use
>   this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
>   both the screen density and the user's preference.

Comment: textSize, not textsize

Answer (score 4):

(1)I think using "dp" or "dip" for text is better than using "sp" because dp(density pixel) adjusts according to screen density. So text will look bigger on High-density devices and smaller on low-density devices.

(2) OR if you specifically want to use "sp" for text size, then you can detect the device density and then set the size of text accordingly:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi){ 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW: 
            //set text-size for low-density devices.
            break; 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: 
            //set text-size for medium-density devices.
            break; 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 
            //set text-size for high-density devices.
            break; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to use different values, Please have a look -

[Different values folders in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)

for more take a look

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

[basics of device-independent-pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707320/basics-of-device-independent-pixels)

OR

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: you can use dip for text also but recommended unit is sp. Changing from sp to dip will only make the situation worse....

Comment: textSize is always SP, not DP. Google made it clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) dimensions, that market as *based on the physical size of screen*. Than texts on all devices will have the same physical size.

Answer (score 2):

The below code adjusts font size scaling in a textView, using the User's system font size setting.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getRealSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
float fontscale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
float textSize = (screenWidth/ fontscale)/10;
Log.e(TAG, "textSize is:  " + textSize);
yourTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,  textSize);
```

Comment: Call requires API level 17 for `display.getRealSize(size);`

Answer (score 1):

TextView headerTextView(String label){

```
    TextView headerTextView = new TextView(this.context);
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    if(scale > 2.0) {
    headerTextView.setWidth(210);
    headerTextView.setHeight(120);
    headerTextView.setTextSize(17);
    }
    else {
        headerTextView.setWidth(125);
        headerTextView.setHeight(60);
        headerTextView.setTextSize(21);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for textSize, google suggested using 'sp' instead of 'dp'
[image]

chcek this link
http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

and for supporting font size for multiple screen you should create new resource for each screen size
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can make use of [scalable DP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and [scalable Font](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) approach.

Android project structure inherently allows specifying different font size (SP) and margin values (DP) by defining them in dimens.xml files for supported screen sizes. But the problem that still remain is - what values to be used ? UX designers normally provide style guides for only one set (e.g. 360x640 DP screen size) and don't provide for all other supported screen sizes. So the problem to use right vlaues for other supported screen sizes still remain unanswered.

One good solution (per my understading) is to use readymade scalable dictionary of dimens.xml files, something similar to the dictionary of files provided by [this](https://github.com/intuit/ssp/tree/master/ssp-android/src/main/res) library. After adding these xml files to project, you just need to use the keys in your layouts, then Android automatically uses font/margin value from respective directory. Please refer [here](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for visual difference - with and without this approach.

Answer (score 0):

TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("Hello World");

// Value is a scaled pixel (SP)
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20f);

// Value is Device Independent Pixels (DIP)
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20f);

// Value is raw pixels (PX)
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 20f);

// Value is in points (PT)
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 20f);

// Value is in millimeters (MM)
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 20f);

// Value is in inches (IN)
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN, 20f);