# How to set same text size in android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm wondering how to make your MainScreen text same size on all devices(I'm using android studio) I have 65dp text, but once I run it on emulator which has bigger screen my text is much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use "dp" for specifying textsizes. Always use "sp" for textsize and "dp" for everything else.

```
android:textSize="25sp"

android:layout_width="50dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the current resolution of the screen and the text size will be proportional for every single device. In this way you could use something like this:

```
//get your textView
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
text.setText("Your title here");
text.setTextSize(65 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

you could do this for every TextView in your MainScreen. Hopefully this helps you :)

P.S. You could find more suggestions for your case here: [Text size with different resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620343/text-size-with-different-resolution)