# Need Standard proportion of values in different dimens.xml android

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, screen-resolution

I'm confused about the values that we use in values/dimens.xml.

For ex. if I've declared the below dimension for text size in values/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="text_30">30sp</dimen>
```

then what should be an equivalent value of 30sp in values-sw600dp/dimens.xml and values-w820dp/dimens.xml ? Is there any proportion/formula that we need to apply while putting values in these different dimens.xml ?

Also same question for **dp values** as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from my understanding. Size will be same for all in `values-sw600dp`, `values-sw720dp`, `values-sw820dp`, but it will auto check device wether it is large or small. try it, may its help you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to calculate for different devices and that's a lengthy way. you can do something like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620562/2031767).

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("text");
text.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

This will always show same text size for all the devices.